# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf - How to show articles by category?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I want to show on the page all the articles from the category I need.

---

**Class Article**

```java
public class Article {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String image;
    private String content;
    private String author;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "categories_articles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_article"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category"))
    private Set<Category> categories;
}
```

**Class Category**

```java
public class Category {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "categories")
    private Set<Article> articles;
}
```

**Service**

```java
    @Override
    public List<Category> findAllCategories() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }
    @Override
    public List<Article> findAllArticles() {
        return articleRepository.findAll();
    }
```

**Controller**

```java
    @GetMapping("/category")
    public String adminAllArticlesByCategory(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAllCategories());
        model.addAttribute("articles", articleService.findAllArticles());
        return "/viewByCategory";
    }
```

This code doesn't work. There are no errors, but for some reason the articles are still not found

**viewByCategory.html**

```html
<section>
    <div th:each="category: ${categories}" th:if="${category.name == 'Tourism'}">
        <div th:if="${!articles.isEmpty()}">
            <div th:each="el : ${articles}">
                <img th:src="${'/images/' + el.image}" th:alt="${el.title}">
                <div>
                    <a th:href="${el.url}" th:text="${el.title}"></a>
                    <span th:text="${el.description}"></span>
                    <span th:text="${#temporals.format(el.created, 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm')}"></span>
                    <span th:text="${el.author}"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 th:if="${articles.isEmpty()}">No Articles</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

What can be done?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help! There are no errors, but for some reason the articles are still not found...

Comment: So are you saying that you are seeing the text "No Articles"?

Comment: Thank you very much !! Your method in the wave controller works!
I needed to additionally change Set<Article> articles; on List<Article> articles;